# Oreo startLocalOnlyHotspot customize SSID and PASSWORD (API 26)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, wifimanager, hotspot

It's just known that since Android Oreo (API 26) is not posible to enable the wifi hotspot as in previous versions, with setApEnable().

Google has hiden and protected those methos, and the only posibility is to enable a local only hotspot with WifiManager.startLocalOnlyHotspot as here is described:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#startLocalOnlyHotspot(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback,%20android.os.Handler)

For my project I need the hotspot funcionality to comunicate with another device, no internet needed but, I need to create the hotspot with some specific credentials that are preconfigured on the other device.

I've checked android documentation but I don't see if it's possible to do a startLocalOnlyHotspot with predefined parameters, SSID and PASSWORD.

Anyone knows if it's possible to configure them?

Thanks!

Comment: hey....did you found the answer or please provide me any workaround solution

Comment: Hi @GowthamanM
Still without a solution about this... I've spended so many ours trying and searching but still nothing.

Comment: same thing for me also....please update answer if you got...if i got i will post my answer

Comment: I think its not possible to change SSID and password, but anyone know how can I broadcast those SSID and Password to nearby users?

Comment: did you get any solutions or workarounds